# How to split a vector into unequal chunks in R based on a condition?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have these two vectors:

```
x <- c(1,2,4,6,7)
y <- c(3,7)
```

How can I split `x` into the elements that are smaller than each element of `y`? For example: `c(1,2) | c(4,6,7)`. 
.

I guess one option would be to do a double loop and return the smallest element in `y` that is smaller than the current one in `x`: `c(3,3,3,7,7)`. I could then split using this vector.

```
j <- 1
sapply(x, function(i){
  if (i <= y[j]) {
    y[j]
  } else {
    if (j < length(y)){
      j <- j + 1
    }
    y[j]
  }
})
```

I feel like there's a cleverer way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Try `ifelse(x>y[1],7,3)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `split` and `findInterval`:

```
split(x, findInterval(x, y, rightmost.closed=TRUE))

$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 4 6 7
```

The `findInterval` function returns a vector that categorizes the variable values in x along your criteria in y. The `split` function separates the vector as desired and returns a named list.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do it:

```
x <- c(1,2,4,6,7)
y <- c(3,7)
out <- list(x[x < min(y)], x[!x < min(y)])
```

Here is the result:

```
> out
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 4 6 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cut` and `split` in base R:

```
lapply(y, function(a) split(x, cut(x, c(-Inf, a, Inf))))

# [[1]]
# [[1]]$`(-Inf,3]`
# [1] 1 2

# [[1]]$`(3, Inf]`
# [1] 4 6 7


# [[2]]
# [[2]]$`(-Inf,7]`
# [1] 1 2 4 6 7

# [[2]]$`(7, Inf]`
# numeric(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the best solution but it is quicker:

```
z <- x < min(y)

end <- x[z]
```